# Errors trying to start F# Interactive (fsi.exe) using System.Diagnostics.Process (.Net Core 3.1)

Tags: c#, .net-core, f#-interactive, .net-core-sdk

I'm trying to start an instance of fsi.exe using System.Diagnostics.Process from an app compiled for .Net Core 3.1.

I'm getting the following errors when executing the code from the .Net Core tools, as described on [MSDN Website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/troubleshoot-usage-issues):

```
Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
Possible reasons for this include:
  * You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
  * You intended to execute a .NET Core program, but dotnet-xyz does not exist.
  * You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.
```

I'm trying the following code, any ideas why this isn't working?

```
   var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
   {
      WorkingDirectory = @"C:\temp\.net core 3.1.0\fsharp",
      FileName = @"dotnet ""C:\Temp\.net core 3.1.0\fsharp\fsi.exe"""
   };

   var process = new Process
   {
      StartInfo = startInfo
   };

   process.Start();
```

Shown below is an example of this working from a console window:

[image]

Comment: maybe you need the full path to `dotnet` too.

Comment: Surround `C:\Temp\.net core 3.1.0\fsharp\fsi.exe` with escaped double quotes.

Comment: @IanKemp already tried this, the example is just missing the \"

Comment: @JohnBoker the required path is already part of the environment PATH variable - added as past of the .Net Core SDK install I believe

Comment: You posted code that is *guaranteed* to fail the exact same way for anybody that looks at your question.  So it is rather important that you explain what you did to ensure it could work.

Comment: looking at the docs, it looks like to execute `dotnet-fsi` or `dotnet fsi` if it's a tool you're trying to run.  If you're just trying to run `fsi.exe` why call it with `dotnet` at all?